# I need to change a value using PHP. Please Help

Tags: php

I've been stuck on this for hours.

How can i manipulate the code below so that the return value is sent to my thank you page (www.website.com/thankyou.php) instead of the root homepage, while keeping everything else intact. The code is listed below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$cfg->wwwroot."registration-confirmed-".base64_encode(serialize(array($user->id, 1)))?>">
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Your question is vague.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: He's trying to pass a parameter to his page that will redirect the user to a new page (that's what the return value is)

Comment: @Joe Philllips Does he want to update a database and redirect?  Post the variable to another page?  Just trying to figure out so a proper answer can be administered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="thankyou.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$cfg->wwwroot."registration-confirmed-".base64_encode(serialize(array($user->id, 1)))?>">
</form>
```

No?

Comment: This is for Paypal's buy now button, so I cannot change the form action.

Comment: Ah, I get your point. I think **@daganh**'s answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the action attribute of the form tag.